# Instantiating a Javascript object without a class and responding?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to be very modular. Like I'm having many js-classes, but I don't want to load them all at firstplace.

When I'm trying to instanciate a new Javascript-Object that is not loaded, it should not work. Using try / catch will trow an reference-error.
Thats fine so far.
What I want is not to use try / catch, treating the new Object as reference error and maybe calling a selfmade-method instead. Is this possible?

E.g.

```
var test = foo('any string',new Test() ); //there is no class called Test()
```

The Object needs to be instanciated into the method foo().
Since there is no class `Test()` and no try / catch is around it, there wont be any error and the code just stops at this point...
It now should call a method (in my case one that loads the class).

Or is there any other way to achieve this effect?
On short: on instanciating and object load an class, not using try catch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you want to do some `amd` stuff. Have a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it much clearer: you still haven't indicated how you would "load" the class if it isn't already available. Load it from where?

Comment: i think it's not required to post how i load it, it would go to deep, just imagine the loading function works fine.

Comment: But is it an asynchronous load? Does the load have some sort of "loaded" callback facility? It's a bit hard for us to suggest ways to integrate with a mystery load function.

Comment: To load class code transparently in a constructor call you would have to use a synchronous network call. That's not good for the user experience. Prefer explicit pre-use-load with callback-when-ready.

Comment: it's synchronous, that's the problem.. it's not possible for me to use 'explicit pre-use-lead'..